# How can I create some deadspace in a contour/vector plot around 2 specific points?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm writing a program meant to plot equipotential contours and acceleration vectors in a 2-body gravitational system. The functions themselves work, but I'd like to tidy up the presentation by removing the contours and vectors within a radius around the two bodies. Is there a way to 'deaden' the space around those points? I'm using matplotlib.pyplot.contour and .quiver, with test points created using numpy.arange and .meshgrid.

Comment: Please create a [reprex].

Comment: Can’t you just draw a circle over the region you want to blank out?